What are some arguments to answer the God Of The Gaps Problem?
If we were to assume that there is a necessary being, what are some arguments that will logically declare that the necessary being is certainly God.
Necessary Being is a being that has to exist, impossible to not exist.

Why should we assume there is a necessary being?

What do you choose to mean by being? What do you choose to mean by God? Indeed, even assuming that the existence of a being is necessary, what do you choose to mean by necessary? Without crisp definitions, your question is not sufficiently formulated to permit any solid answers.

And by the way, how do you understand the question in the body of your post to relate to the question in your title?

@Hido There are no arguments at all that a necesary being is God. - I assume that you mean by God the Jewish god Jahwe. A being is not necessarily a person. It could be any other god from a different religion, but also the universe as a whole. There are many further candidates. - In addition, I question the truth of your assumption, that a necessary being exists. At least you do not give any argument, which is required for a philosophical discussion.

VTC because this is largely a question as written of opinion in philosophical discourse. It might find a receptive audience on Christianity SE

There is plenty of criticism in this Wiki page :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_the_gaps

You are looking, I think, for "ontological arguments".  There are any number of these.  Anselm's of Canterbury is possibly the most famous.

Question should state which god,  there are so many. And should better explain the assumption.

There were 8 billion necessary beings running around, last time I checked.


What are some arguments to answer the God Of The Gaps Problem?

The "God of the Gaps" fallacy is a logical fallacy that assumes a lack of scientific knowledge is evidence of supernatural intervention:


Note that this is not a "problem" unless you are seeking evidence for a deity's existence either to counter your own doubts or to proselytize. If you accept that the deity worked through natural laws as we understand them rather than miracles, there are no gaps that need to be explained away and you can focus on celebrating God's creativity.  Admittedly, that makes a poor argument for proselytizing with.

@keshlam yeah, it's not a popular slogan: "Yay! Parasitic wasps! Great world!"

You ask two things:


What are some arguments to answer the God Of The Gaps Problem?
If we were to assume that there is a necessary being, what are some arguments that will logically declare that the necessary being is certainly God?


First, you have not actually described the "God of the gaps problem."
But to answer your question #2: if we assume as a premise that "there is a necessary being" then there is nothing incongruous with naming that thing "God." At that point, it would just be a matter of semantic convention.

No argument here.
